# Microsoft.Phone.Tasks namespace is not available

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

Namespace `Microsoft.Phone.Tasks` is not available in XAML page code behind file of my Windows Phone application. Please see the screenshot.

[image]

In the properties windows of the project I see:

```
Target: Windows Phone 8.1
```

Am I missing an assembly reference or something?

Comment: Is that a Windows Runtime app? Microsoft.Phone.Tasks only esists in Silverlight apps.

Comment: @the_nuts it is Windows Phone Empty(Blank) Silverlight application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows Phone 8.1 XAML apps don't have Microsoft.Phone.Tasks namespace to make common UI framework with windows Runtime APIs. Still you can code up a few tasks by using Windows.ApplicationModel namespace. As you havent claried which task you want to use, so here's the link to the whole MSDN article. http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/WindowsPhone-Store-81-vs-25c80c2a

Answer (score 1):

From your Screenshot. I see your project is **Windows Phone 8.1**, not `Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1` . Please see your Solution Explorer, is it Windows Phone 8.1? If so, there are not `Microsoft.Phone.Tasks` namespace anymore. If you want to choose picture, you should use `FileOpenPicker`.