# Windows 8.1, Adding camera capture task not importing?

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, camera, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to put a camera capturing task/event into my application I'm building. But everytime I try to do the import, "using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;" It gives me an error and "phone" is highlighted in red. Can't seem to figure out what the bug is, can anyone help?

Here's an image of my problem.

![problem] file:///C:/Users/Qamar/Desktop/Problem.png

thanks!

Comment: You'll need to upload that image to imgur or similar so anyone else can view it.

Answer (score 0):

Think you're using WP8.1 runtime, so that namespace is not available.

See [microsoft-phone-tasks-namespace-is-not-available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24997435/microsoft-phone-tasks-namespace-is-not-available)

---

In WP8.1 runtime you need to use [Windows.Phone.Media.Capture namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.phone.media.capture.aspx) for most of your camera needs.